# Advanced text editing for VBA (excel) textbox

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

**Preamble**

Recently I've been struggling with big excel spreadsheets that have a lot of text and comments (multiple people work on single document). It is tremendously hard to  edit it again and again (considering new notes), since document navigating becomes pretty complicated at some point. So, I decided that I need some tool to get/set only the data I actually need at one moment (single cell content, corresponsive comment content, additional data for the cell's row on demand).

**What is done so far**

Fortunatelly the start was pretty easy. I filled UserForm with 4 textboxes (2 readonly, 2 for editing), that are filled with data of the selected comment (by index), and some buttons that allow to accept/discard changes and navigate between commented cells.

**Questions itself**

First of all, I need to keep text formatting when I take the text from cell. Currently I am not taking any formatting, just text. All I found by googling is that I can set formatting character by character, sort of like in the following pseudocode:

```
For i = 0 to Cells(Row, Col).Text.Length
    MyTextBox.Text(i).FormatOption1 = Cells(Row, Col).Text(i).FormatOption1
    ...
    MyTextBox.Text(i).FormatOptionN = Cells(Row, Col).Text(i).FormatOptionN
Next
```

But this approach feels to be stupid. So, question one is:

*Is there a way to copy full text formatting (Font, B/I/U, color, Size for each letter in the cell) alongside with text, from cell to TextBox and backwards, with one line of code?*

Second of all I actually need some formatting tools in the UserForm to do aforesaid text formatting in my form, so question two is:

*Is there a way to add formatting tools (the ones that are located in Home->Font menu, or popup menu when you select some text in a cell) into UserForm to edit text in TextBox object?*

P.S. using Excel 2013

A bit of addition:
I somehow assume that if there is no direct way to do what I've described in questions - there has to be some custom-made toolbox object (sort of EvenRicherTextBox) that was created by someone before. I just cannot believe that issue never came up, but I have no idea what keywords I need to use in order to find that object.

Comment: There is probably a way to do this, but its going to be quite code intensive.  There is no 'formatting' tag in vba, and each part of the formatting is a seperate code string. Is the type of formats you are after fairly limited ie bold, italic, basic fonts etc - or are you looking for quite a bit of variety?

If you record copying formatting between two cells, it will give you an idea of the VBA commands you might need for some of the formats.

Comment: There is something going wrong here. *MyTextBox.Font.Bold = Cells(Row,Col).Font.Bold*, this works perfectly with me, (as well for italic and underline options), there is no need to iterate through each character in the text. Is there any specific option that does not work this way??

Comment: oh maybe i got it, you have many lines inside each cell, and each line has a different formatting, right?

Comment: @A.S.H it could be not just a line. I could be highlighted word, or even a letter, within one of the lines. It looks more like a MS Word text, rather than something suitable for excel.

Comment: @Trum Theoretically that menu I've been talking about in the second question can be made by myself, since we got all that functionality in objects and methods of Cell and TextBox objects. But making an amature recreation of something that already implemented in the original program seems to be a wrong path.

Comment: One tricky solution is to use a richText control, such as MS InkEdit control. It uses RTF format, but exchanging this formatting with Excel is tricky (Excel does not use RTF), you might need to pass this exchange through some hidden instance of MS-Word.

Comment: Hi @Denis I more meant if you were trying to pull through the original cell formatting - this would be your best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create a custom class for this, here's an example of how it might look:

***Class Module code (name the module "FormattedString")***

```
Option Base 1

Private Type FSChar
    Letter      As Integer
    Bold        As Boolean
    Italic      As Boolean
    Underline   As Boolean
    Colour      As Long
    Size        As Integer
End Type

Private strCollection() As FSChar
Private strRange        As Excel.Range
Private txt             As String  


Public Property Let FString(value As Excel.Range)

    Set strRange = value
    txt = strRange.text

    ReDim strCollection(1 To Len(strRange.text)) As FSChar

    For i = 1 To Len(strRange.text)
        With strCollection(i)
            .Letter = Asc(Mid(strRange.text, i, 1))
            .Bold = (strRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True)
            .Italic = (strRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True)
            .Underline = (strRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = True)
            .Colour = strRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex
            .Size = strRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
        End With
    Next

End Property


Public Property Get FString() As Excel.Range
    Set FString = strRange
End Property


Public Sub WriteFStringToCell(ByRef writeCell As Range)

writeCell.value = txt

    For i = 1 To UBound(strCollection)
        With writeCell.Characters(i, 1).Font
            .Bold = strCollection(i).Bold
            .Italic = strCollection(i).Italic
            .Underline = strCollection(i).Underline
            .ColorIndex = strCollection(i).Colour
            .Size = strCollection(i).Size
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

***Example:***
*(Write something in A1 and format with different styles etc...)*

```
Sub MacroMan()

Dim testClass As FormattedString
Set testClass = New FormattedString

testClass.FString = Range("A1")

testClass.WriteFStringToCell Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: That is generally the approach I wanted to avoid. Anyways, thanks for explanation given, I think I'd use it if nothing else comes up. Do you have any ideas about second question as well? That one seems to be way more complicated.

Comment: I think someone already mentioned the RTF tools - probably the best option. You could create a series of context menus via winAPI but if you got any of that wrong then bye bye workbook.....